# Error 404 after migrating to server

Tags: magento-1.8

I am getting 404 error. Only home page is working only.

Can anybody tell me what could be reason for that

Thanks

Comment: Did you check to make sure your .htaccess is working? Try adding index.php between your domain name and page url eg domain.com/index.php/path/to/page.php

Comment: yes by adding index.php is working. what should  i do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue have something to do with your server not processing your .htaccess file which can be cause by many different things.

1. Check to make sure you have .htaccess in your server root folder
2. Check your magento setting see [How to remove index.php from URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474740/how-to-remove-index-php-from-urls)?
3. Your server master apache config (AllowOverride) may not setup correctly see [.htaccess not working apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache)

Comment: root folder means where my exact setup for magento

Comment: Where you have index.php, var, skin, app, etc

Answer (score 1):

Check if mod_rewrite is enabled on server and if .htaccess is used.
If you can't enable it you should disable SEO in Magento / Admin / System / Configuration / General / Web / Search Engine Optimization